# Block level element(<aside>) wont show?

Tags: html, css, github

My `aside` element won't display on my webpage. On my local machine it displays fine, but when I uploaded it to GitHub and copy/paste it to CodePen, it won't show itself.

It's supposed to be floating on the right of the `#mainArticle` but its empty.

[Heres the site](https://jrod08.github.io/projects/) and [heres the code (html and css)](https://github.com/Jrod08/projects). The missing element looks just like the `#relatedNews` on the left side, both are pretty much the same, just float different sides.

**Edit:** So I got it to work on FireFox, Chrome on my mobile phone just won't work on Chrome for my laptop

**Edit 2:** Well I was able to get a hold of my sisters laptop and it works fine on hers. I guess it's just displaying it differently on my browser which is weird but I'm happy as long as its working on everyone elses browser.

**Edit 3:** Thanks to @Paulie_D it was something soooo simple turned off adblocker and it worked guess you can tell im a noob still haha:p

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
   
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

hr{
    margin: 0px 51px 0px 51px;
    border-color: #FAFAFA;
}
h1{
    display: inline-block;
}


/*containers*/
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
}
/*text classes*/
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
.card-text{
    margin: 8px;
}

/*id's*/
#header{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 45px;
    
}
/*floats left of #mainArticke*/
#relatedNews{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
/*Center between #relatedNews and #ads*/
#mainArticle{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin:5px;
    
}
/*floats on right side of #mainArticle*/
#ads{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Colors*/
.white{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

/*grid*/
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 65%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

/*media*/
/*#mainArticle becomes absolute*/
@media screen and (max-width:1098px){
    #mainArticle{
        position: absolute;
    }
}
/*floats #relatedNews and #ads to right #mainArticle becomes absolute*/
@media screen and (max-width:1100px){

    #relatedNews{
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        width: 33.33%;
        
    }
    /*Clears below #relatedNews*/
    #ads{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        float: right;
        width: 33.33%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

/*#relatedNews and #ads sit below #mainArticle */
@media screen and (max-width:650px){
    #mainArticle{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #relatedNews{
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
    
    }
    #ads{
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        width: 49%;
        margin-left: 5px;
        
    }
}
/*Removes margin on smaller devices*/
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .container{
        margin: 0;
    }
    #mainArticle{
        width:inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #relatedNews{
        width: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #ads{
        width: inherit;
        margin: 0; 
    }
}
```

```html
  <header class="white col-12" id="header">
        <h1>World Wide News!</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="col-8 white" id="mainArticle">
            <article class="card-text"><header><h2 class="text-center">Main Article!</h2></header>
                <p>And nu</p>
                <br><p>I'veast</p><br>
                <hr>
               <br>
                <p>Rain so poisoned, rainbows flowing. If me and Future hadn't made it with this rappin'. Yted more<br>

                <br>I've been fade'Cause I'm on one. Yeah, it's been too long. for real. A whole lot of girls, first flight from Poland<br>


                    When your famous girlI'd rather give that 15% to people I fuck with. It gets worse by the annual my career's like a how to manual. I'm on one<br>


                    <br>I can still get spoke in so long, probably put me in the past</p>
            </article>
        </section>

         <aside class="col-2 white" id="relatedNews"><header><h3 class="text-center">Related News!</h3></header>
        <article class="card-text">
            <p>
                Wallets, wallets,an see it in your eyes, you're angry. Forget 3 SUV'S, for, distress like refugees</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
        <aside class="col-2 white" id="ads">
            <header><h3 class="text-center">Sponsored By!</h3></header>
            <article class="card-text">
            <p>
                Wallets, wallets,e real live forever man. We prolly be out in Silicon tryna get our billions on. I can see it in your eyes, you're angry. Forget 3 SUV'S, for, distress like refugees</p>
        </article>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - when describing your issue, [create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *shows* the issue you experiencing. Not only does it help us see the issue, but sometimes while creating the example, you can figure out what the problem is and solve it before you even need to ask! Further, you should be very detailed when describing your issue and avoid using phrases like *"Its supposed to be floating"* - what is *it*, what is the name of the element? These are questions people trying to help solve shouldn't need to ask themselves

Comment: I edited it I cant create an example because I dont know what wrong to recreate it. It looks fine to me everyone I asked has no idea

Comment: `#ads` displays fine here, in multiple browsers - what browser are you experiencing this issue? did you try multiple and is the problem on all of them or just a specific browser?

Comment: I added the markup to your question. *This* is what is meant by an example. (note I removed unnecessary text, but let all elements in tact). There's a little "code" button you can click to insert markup and scripting. As @justinw pointed out, reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve may be helpful to get better responses to questions. --- Based on what I'm seeing I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that @Scott, sorry first time posting here. Well it seems to be working on FireFox and chrome on my android phone. Yet #ads wont display on chrome on my laptop

Comment: With an ID of `#ads`...it's likely that it's being hidden by an **adblocker**

Comment: WOW @Paulie_D I feel soooooooooo dumb smh thank you